# Android dynamically set theme not working

Tags: android, styles, android-theme

In My application :

```
setTheme(R.style.sometheme)
```

does not work same when theme is set in manifest, for activity tag as below:
**`android:theme="@style/sometheme"`**

I need to set the theme *dynamically*, in the android application `onCreate` . I can't do this, since the behavior of both the implementations is different.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.. 
'setTheme(R.style.sometheme)' takes some time to apply, so if you put certain delay, you could see it. Where as if you apply the theme in manifest, it is applied instantly.